# JQuery: Posting Files with FormData-Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, django-models

So i am using a ModelForm for an updateview and want to append some files using a Javascript FormData-Object, submiting the whole form using JQuery.

It seems, that the Image-Files dont get posted.

**views.py**:

```
class SowiUpdateView(UserPassesTestMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.POST)
        return super(SowiUpdateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**The javascript:**

```
var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("form_id"));

for (var i = 0, len = filesToUpload.length; i < len; i++) { // filesToUpoad is a List containing a dict, with file i access the file
    formData.append("files", filesToUpload[i].file);
}

$.ajax({
    headers: { "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken") },
    url: "{% url 'sowi-update' object.id %}",
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    async: false,
    method: 'POST',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        // console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log("ERROR - " + data.responseText);
    }
});
```

Strangely, the serverside-post-data-output gives all the FormData-Data but the "files"-object. What's wrong? I Tried just appending a string instead of a file, and that worked.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: assdfasdfasdfasdfasdf